# Moving from Angular 7 to 8 with ObservableMedia in @angular/flex-layout

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I have a couple of issues that I cannot resolve.

original code snippet:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ObservableMedia } from '@angular/flex-layout';

…..export class MyClass {

readonly breakpointsToColumnsNumber = new Map([
    ['xs', 1],
    ['sm', 2],
    ['md', 3],
    ['lg', 4],
    ['xl', 5],
  ]);

constructor(private media: ObservableMedia ) {
  this.columns$ = this.media.asObservable().pipe(map(mc => <number>this.breakpointsToColumnsNumber.get(mc.mqAlias)));

}
```

Now after moving to Angular 8, ObservableMedia has been deprecated and is now

> MediaObserver

so I change my import line and the object type being passed in to the constructor to this:

```
import { MediaObserver } from '@angular/flex-layout';

constructor(private media: MediaObserver)…
```

Now I get 2 errors:

declaring new MAP : Cannot find 'Map'. Do you need to change your target Library? try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later. (in my tsconfig file I have `lib' set to es2017 and dom, but even adding es2015 doesn't remove this.

2nd error is on the Lambda mc.mqAlias : Property 'mqAlias' does not exist on type 'MediaChange[]' - looking on the new object, I cannot see anything that looks the equivalent of this.

Answer (score 0):

## 1st error:

You might be missing

> lib.es2015.collection.d.ts

file in your *lib* folder.

## 2nd error:

in this case *asObservable()* method passes *MediaChange[]* type onto `mc`. In order to access mqAlias property you need to make sure that `mc` is of type *MediaChange*. You may do so by using *media$* instead of *asObservable()*.
Your code may end up looking something like this:

```js
import { MediaObserver } from '@angular/flex-layout';

    ...

constructor(private media: MediaObserver) {
    this.columns$ = this.media.media$.pipe(map(mc => <number>this.breakpointsToColumnsNumber.get(mc.mqAlias)));
    }
```

And since media$ is mapped to the first item in the *MediaChange[]* array You may also use this code:

```js
this.columns$ = this.media.asObservable()
    .pipe(
        map(mc => <number>this.breakpointsToColumnsNumber.get(mc[0].mqAlias))
);
```